# Number of ways to write $k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m = n$, $k_i\ge 0$. What am I missing?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the solution I know: think of the problem as that of finding a number of ways of putting $n$ identical balls into $m$ numbered boxes. Position the balls in a line with spaces between them and take $m+1$ identical barriers. Place two barriers at the ends of the line and leave them fixed, and distribute the other $m-1$ barriers randomly in spaces between the balls. We get all possible positions if we permute everything between the two barriers at the ends in all possible ways (in total that is $n+m-1$ elements to permute). However, permuting the balls between themselves or barriers between themselves leaves the position intact, so that all distinct positions are counted $n!\cdot (m-1)!$ times and the answer is
$$
\frac{(n+m-1)!}{n!(m-1)!} = {n+m-1\choose n}.
$$
Once you know the answer, there are shorter solutions that come to mind as well.

The following argument seems equally convincing, and gives a nonsensical answer: again, position the balls in a line left to right with spaces between them and take $m+1$ barriers, place two barriers at the ends so that there are spaces between the left barrier and the leftmost ball and the right barrier and the rightmost ball. There is one way of doing this. Now there are $n+1$ spaces into which we can put the $m-1$ barriers (possibly more than one next to each other into a single space). We get all possible configurations if we leave the balls fixed and simply place the barriers in all possible ways. The number of ways to do this is the number of maps from a set of $m-1$ elements to a set of $n+1$ elements, namely $(n+1)^{m-1}$, and permuting the barriers does not change the configuration, so we get
$$\frac{(n+1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}$$
This, however, is not even an integer generally. Why is the second argument wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You can get two barriers between the same two balls, and which order you place them there is irrelevant. Not that $(n+1)^{m-1}/(m-1)!$ is generally not an integer... Basically, all $(m-1)!$ rearrangements of the barriers don't give different barrier placements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n=3$ and $m=3$. Then $0+0+3=3$ amounts to placing two barriers in the first position. There is only one way to do so, not $2!$ different ways to do so.

Comment: We could do the same with the first argument by putting two barriers (or balls) next to each other. So, the problem is that we can only permute objects which occupy destinguishable "places"?

Comment: No, there is only one subset if the $n+m-1$ elements of size $m-1$ that corresponds to an individual partition. See the "stars and bars" web page at Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) @Artem

Comment: For example, the $0+0+3$ sum is represented in the first argument as taking $\{1,2\}$ out of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. It is not represented any other way. So there are $\frac{5\cdot 4}{2\cdot 1}$ different ways to pick two elements out of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Basically, the first argument avoids the problem of picking the same "barrier location" twice.

Comment: The second argument does work for *positive* partitions, because then we can only place one barrier in each position, so there would be $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose the position of the barriers.